# Online resources for learning Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

Not sure if this is the place for it, but there are similar posts for podcasts and blogs, so I'll post this one. I'd be interested in seeing a list of online resources for mathematics learning.

As someone doing a non-maths degree in college I'd be interested in finding some resources for learning more maths online, most resources I know of tend to either assume a working knowledge of maths beyond secondary school level, or only provide a brief summary of the topic at hand.

I'll start off by posting [MIT Open Courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/), which is a large collection of lecture notes, assignments and multimedia for the MIT mathematics courses, although in many places it's quite incomplete.

Comment: Mathematics Educators is another place to ask. They're happy to have questions about learning, not just teaching. (I think they might also consider it too general though.)

Answer (score 12):

The following reddit post has a decent list of math resources:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/bqbex/lets_list_all_the_useful_free_online_math/

One site I did not see it their list that I've found very helpful:

- http://betterexplained.com/

Answer (score 8):

- Khan Academy, http://www.khanacademy.org/
- You'll find tons of explanatory videos from various branches of mathematics; plus, each subject is explained pretty good, and the videos are easy to follow

Comment: Khan Academy is terrible. Try MIT's opencourseware instead.

Comment: @Harry: If this is an answer, post an answer. If you think this answer is unhelpful, downvote. Please don't use the comments to provide nonconstructive criticism.

Comment: I have seen over half of Khan Academy's math videos and done nearly all exercises. I am now studying pure mathematics at college. Khan academy's math is good for getting a basic understanding of math, or if your math skillset crumbled somewhere along your highschool education, like it did for me.
But there is a huge difference between KA's math level and college math. If you're serious about learning math, and you already have a decent understanding of the basics, I'd say don't bother with Khan Academy. If you never really understood math well though, it might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Andrea Feretti's [MathOnline](http://mathonline.andreaferretti.it/) page.

Answer (score 4):

A useful one for undergraduate level maths is [Mathcentre](http://www.mathscentre.ac.uk/).  It has useful background material for people studying maths, or who need some maths background for other courses.

Comment: That, and the associated http://www.mathtutor.ac.uk/ site, are more pre-undergraduate in UK terms, though still worthwhile

Answer (score 4):

[**Purplemath**](http://www.purplemath.com/lessons.htm) has a list for math lessons and tutoring. It's a list with various links and short reviews referring to tutoring and instructional resources.

Answer (score 4):

For basic mathematics [mathpage](http://www.themathpage.com/Arith/arithmetic.htm) has a long course, including the list below. Don't be put off by the elementary school style lesson names, it does go into some depth with each one.

```
Lesson 1    Reading and Writing Whole Numbers
Lesson 2    The Meaning of Decimals
Lesson 3    Multiplying and Dividing
Lesson 4    More Elementary Addition
Lesson 5    Adding Whole Numbers and Decimals
Lesson 6    The Meaning of Subtraction
Lesson 7    Subtracting Whole Numbers and
Lesson 8    The Meaning of Multiplication
Lesson 9     Multiplying Whole Numbers
Lesson 10    The Meaning of Division
Lesson 11    Short Division
Lesson 12    Dividing Decimals  
Lesson 13    Percent with a Calculator  
Lesson 14    Parts of Natural Numbers 1  
Lesson 15    Parts of Natural Numbers 2  
Lesson 16    Ratio and Proportion  1  
Lesson 17    Ratio and Proportion  2  
Lesson 18    Proportionality  
Lesson 19    Proper Fractions, Mixed Numbers
Lesson 20    Unit Fractions  
Lesson 21    Equivalent Fractions  
Lesson 22    Lowest Common Multiple  
Lesson 23    Fractions into Decimals  
Lesson 24    Adding and Subtracting Fractions 
Lesson 25    Multiplying Fractions 
Lesson 26    The Meaning of Multiplying Fractions
Lesson 27    Percents are Ratios  
Lesson 28    Percent of a Number  
Lesson 29    What Percent?
Lesson 30    Percent Increase or Decrease  
Lesson 31    Prime Numbers  
Lesson 32    Greatest Common Divisor
```

Answer (score 3):

Two good general references:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aMathematics)
- [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/)

Comment: Though a lot of the Wikipedia articles assume quite advanced knowledge on the part of the reader, especially knowledge of advanced notation.

Answer (score 3):

J. Milne has publicized his lecture notes for free, complete with exercises in fields such as group theory, field theory, algebraic geometry, algebraic number theory, "and so on". http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/index.html (probably best suited for upper undergrad or grad students, though)

Answer (score 3):

Paul's Online Notes seem to be very good:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/

They cover most basic math courses that an undergraduate would take.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.redhoop.org/search/?q=math. It lists free and paid online courses on math