# How i can learn mathematics these days?

Tags: math-software, learning

i am currently have no idea where i can learn mathematics online. whenever i am in schools my math goes too bad but now i want to learn mathematics online.

any idea where i can get education for mathematics for just hobby and fun with learning advanced things.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90/online-resources-for-learning-mathematics

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#mathematics

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should learn mathematics *from* someone and *with* someone (different someones). You should also read books and do as many problems as possible. So look for a college and a library nearby. It's hard to give further advice without knowing more details.

Answer (score 3):

The Khan Academy has great resources, including video. http://www.khanacademy.org

As mentioned in the comments, MIT has some good course materials at ocw.mit.edu/courses.

I would really recommend a library and actual books - one needs to do problems to learn math. Many problems. Easy and hard. One needs to rack one's brain into thinking about things in potentially very different ways. In that, lhf is right on.

If we knew what sorts of math you've done, or what you'd like to do, we could even tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

So I hear you want to learn mathematics. Well this is a journey that you must be patient with because it will take time and lots of practice to get comfortable with a lot of the topics. In regards to self study, I would suggest looking over video's and some books that are not too heavy on mathematical language to begin with: Some dvd video's would be this below:

1)  http://www.mathtutordvd.com/

Also, there are some free videos online:

2)  http://www.youtube.com/user/mathtutordvd

3)  http://www.youtube.com/user/patrickJMT?blend=1&ob=5

So far as books, I do not really know what type of math you are wanting to start off learning, so these websites should be a great start, as they cover a wide range of different topics.

Okay, I hope this helps you out.

Good Luck with your studies.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of sources listed above, but sometimes a person might not do well in a classroom. I enrolled in an online calculus III class and taught myself...maybe it has to do with a math book as well.