# Resource recommendations for learning Grade 10 Geometry and Algebra?

Tags: reference-request

Is there any free online courses that would start from, say, 'grade-10' level in Geometry and Algebra?

Please recommend books or websites for summaries of Euclidean Geometry and Pre-College Algebra? Summaries as in general ideas that get specific in several details and allows for a good head-start without college aid.

---

I found this:

1. *(19-03-2012)* This's for those (like me) starting from grade-10 level. I'm already working in it. (3 books) http://cnx.org/lenses/fhsst/affiliation1
2. William suggested OCW. It's not the format I'm looking for; I'm looking for coherent, ***self-contained*** courses. The site did, however, include http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/ocw-scholar/#math.
3. SMSG books were suggested below. Use the first link posted in the answer and change the *.pdf name between [135 616, 135 630). I'll confirm the later sequences.
4. I haven't tried this but it appears authentic: http://www.uccs.edu/~math/vidarchive.html
5. I also found [Online resources for learning Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90/online-resources-for-learning-mathematics), http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/.

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from MIT opencourseware.  By elementary algebra, do you mean high-school/college algebra, or abstract algebra?  There's an [MIT course on abstract algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-701-algebra-i-fall-2010/index.htm).

Answer (score 6):

I have several print copies of a sequence of U.S. "new math" textbooks from the 1960s that might be very useful to you, if you can find them on the internet. Google the phrase "school mathematics study group" (SMSG) and perhaps you can find some .pdf files of them posted somewhere. For those who think these books might be overly pseudo-set-theoretical (because of other books/literature written at the time that were overly pseudo-set-theoretical and a number of second rate teacher workshops that took place back then), I'll mention that these books were put out by the same people who began the MAA "New Mathematical Library" series of books. Below are some SMSG texts that I've managed to find on-line. I've listed them in an approximate order of their content level.

**First Course in Algebra**, Student's Text, Part I, Unit 9

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135617.pdf

**First Course in Algebra**, Student's Text, Part II, Unit 10

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135618.pdf

**First Course in Algebra**, Part 3. Preliminary Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED186227.pdf

**Geometry**, Student's Text, Part I, Unit 13. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135621.pdf

**Geometry**, Student's Text, Part II, Unit 14. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135622.pdf

**Intermediate Mathematics**, Student's Text, Part I, Unit 17

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135625.pdf

**Intermediate Mathematics**, Part 1, Supplementary Unit I. The Development of the Real Number System. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED143529.pdf

**Intermediate Mathematics**, Student's Text, Part II, Unit No. 18. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED173087.pdf

**Geometry with Coordinates**, Student's Text, Part I, Unit 47. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED160452.pdf

**Geometry with Coordinates**, Student's Text, Part II, Unit 48. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED160453.pdf

**Elementary Functions**, Student's Text, Unit 21

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135629.pdf

**Analytic Geometry**, Student Text, Part 1. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED184826.pdf

**Analytic Geometry**, Student Text, Part 3. Revised Edition

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED184830.pdf

**Introduction to Matrix Algebra**, Student's Text, Unit 23

http://www.eric.ed.gov/PDFS/ED135631.pdf

Comment: I'm afraid I can't try all those due to my bandwidth but I'll sure look for the title you emphasized and see if I could get a link for the whole collection and download it from a cafe or something.

Comment: I'm afraid the links you have provided no longer work. Would you have an alternative?