# I need an introductory/intermediate algebra book recommendations

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the grip of geometry and Algebra; books and resources for a beginner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122421/getting-the-grip-of-geometry-and-algebra-books-and-resources-for-a-beginner)

I am learning programing on my own. I work on exercises from a book. The problem I have is that most of the exercises are heavily concentrated on math and Algebra. I can solve it WHEN I understand the word problem and have the proper math knowledge. I did not deal with math long time ago. So I was searching for a good Algebra book to enhance my math skills. . I found that this book
[http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Trigonometry-8th-Edition-Larson/dp/1439048479/ref=pd_sim_b_7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439048479)

Algebra and trigonometry by Ron Larson has good reviews. But I am not sure if it's the right one for me. I'd like to hear from you. Any recommendations

Comment: Algebra is a huge subject. can you give an example of suchg exercises, you need to solve.

Comment: I tried starting "Linear Algebra" by Jim Hefferson, but found it fairly abstract.  I recommend Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra." This is the textbook for [MIT Linear Algebra 18.06](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/), and the lectures on Open Courseware are helpful for important topics.

Comment: The previous question is more broad and already has an answer full of links.