# How to get a top-notch Math education (high school level) online?

Tags: math-history, education

For the past years, it is becoming more and more accessible to get college level content from many different sources, and, if one is willing can get very far with his math education (not only by watching video classes, but by using sites like this, etc) using online resources.

But what I feel lacking are online resources to get someone to be very good at Math on a High School level. Why there is not some MOOC to teach high school Math concepts? Why there is not other courses?

If you could devise a whole High School Math curricula to be available online, how would you shape it?

I know that it is a far broad question, but I do hope that it is not off-topic.

Comment: Khan academy does a very nice job.  http://www.khanacademy.org/ Beyond that, I would just suggest you get a book with lots of questions and answers.

Comment: any book(s) in mind?

Comment: Thomas's calculus  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=thomas%27s+calculus

Comment: I think the psychology of having "too many choices" (which you can google about) is at play here. Indeed, I wonder if I would study math if I was growing up today. My high school didn't offer calculus, and there was only one calculus text at my county's public library (none at my school's library), Edwin Joseph Purcell's 1968 **Calculus With Analytic Geometry**, so I worked through it during my 10th grade year hoping to get an edge in college level math, like a basketball player practicing basketball on weekends and off-season to be better. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** I'm afraid that if I had any idea of how much mathematics existed beyond calculus, and had near immediate access to the tens of thousands of books and freely available journal papers that people have today, I suspect I would have drowned in the choices available and not have gotten anywhere. Anyway, to partially answer your question, see the many freely available books I gave in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122421/getting-the-grip-of-geometry-and-algebra-books-and-resources-for-a-beginner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing resources (in English, in the US) include:

1. [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/): an online discussion forum plus relatively inexpensive courses, up through calculus.
2. John Hopkins' [Center for Talented Youth](http://cty.jhu.edu/): the [online math courses](http://cty.jhu.edu/ctyonline/courses/mathematics/) include the standard high school curriculum from Algebra I through Calc, as well as higher level topics such as Linear Algebra and Abstract Math (I love their first assignment -- prepare a [beamer presentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) of Euclid's proof of Pythagorean theorem). This is more expensive, and requires placement through a gifted student search -- you have to take ACT or SAT in your middle school or early in high school.
3. Stanford's [Education Program for Gifted Youth](http://epgy.stanford.edu/for-parents/epgy-courses/courses) offers the standard high school courses through Calculus. Requires placement through the gifted student search -- you have to be placed through high performance on either one of the regular American standardized tests, special IQ-type tests for high achieving students, or through early ACT/SAT/PSAT.

I imagine that other countries have their own specific resources. I am a native of Russia, so if you are a Russian speaker, you can take a look at [Moscow Center for Continuing Math Education](http://www.mccme.ru/). (If you are not, run Google translate on [Problem of the day](http://problems.ru/), they usually take one or two sentences to set up, and two or three pages to solve.)